# Creating JDBC driver in R using RJDBC

Tags: mysql, r, jdbc, data-science, rjdbc

I am trying to create a JDBC driver in R using following code:
i have already set the directory to location where .jar folder is located

```
drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin-g.jar",
            identifier.quote="`")
```

i get the following error:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

what would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me i.e. i do not get "class not found" error. I downloaded [mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=460363) into my current working directory and ran the below without issues

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    classPath="mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar",
    identifier.quote="`")
```

Comment: can you give some information about your JVM version?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem loading the script `drv <- JDBC("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","PATH_to_jar", ...)` in R, although the PATH was correct. There was a Java update in my Linux distro  which caused the package rJava or RJDBC not to work anymore. Unfortunately, the error message was that class `com.mysql.jdbc.Util` could not be found when executing the subsequent `dbConnect(drv, ...)` after this update. This was a bit strange and took me a while to figure out that the package was broken, because it loaded correctly using `library(RJDBC)`.

My solution was to reinstall rJava and RJDBC to make it work again (`packages.install("rJava") packages.install("RJDBC")`).  I recognized it was a Linux problem since the code worked fine in RStudio on Windows.